# No file in debug folder in C# project

Tags: c#

When I created a new C# project this morning using Visual Studio, I realized there is no file in Debug folder although in previous projects, this situation does not happen. Is there any way I can do to fix this ( I have tried reinstalling Visual Studio )

I have tried to create a new C# project and delete the old one, reinstalling Visual Studio but things didn't change

Comment: Press "Rebuild Project" or "Build Project"?

Comment: When you compile a project, you can set the output folder to Debug or Release. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-set-debug-and-release-configurations?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 1):

1: Did you verify that the project can build? If the project cannot build, no files will be created, as there is nothing to store in the folder.

2: Did you verify that the folder is configured to be the destination for said project? You can define output folders for projects, to not be in their default location.

3: Are you sure you are in the correct parent folder when looking for the debug folder , usually there is a "bin" folder first.

4: Please show you project definition for builds.

Like in this image below.
[image: screenshot of properties for project]